# Javafx FXML Incompatible

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm generating FXML in JavaFX Scene Builder 11.0.0, but it gives errors in execution, when I use Netbeans 11 generated FXML it runs but then the work of creating interfaces is more difficult. Does anyone know how to resolve this incompatibility?

```
Executing C:\Users\eder\Documents\NetBeansProjects\OlaMundojavafx\dist\run1313104556\OlaMundojavafx.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction=’#handleButtonAction’, either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
file:/C:/Users/eder/Documents/NetBeansProjects/OlaMundojavafx/dist/run1313104556/OlaMundojavafx.jar!/olamundojavafx/FXMLDocument.fxml:11

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:103)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:610)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:770)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at olamundojavafx.OlaMundojavafx.start(OlaMundojavafx.java:22)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$3(WinApplication.java:177)
... 1 more
Exception running application olamundojavafx.OlaMundojavafx
Java Result: 1
Deleting directory C:\Users\eder\Documents\NetBeansProjects\OlaMundojavafx\dist\run1313104556
jfxsa-run-no-another-jvm:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: What are the errors you're getting? Can you provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem?

Comment: We need to see the controller class to answer this. It would also be preferrable to include the element at line 11 in the fxml in the question.